# .push() and .pop working backwards?

Tags: groovy

I am starting to pick up Groovy syntax and I ran the following code:

```
def nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
nums.pop()
println(nums)
```

...which gives me an output of `[2,3,4,5]`. I also tried .push in the following manner:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
nums.push(99)
println(nums)
```

...which gives me an output of `[99,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Shouldn't both of those functions have targeted the end of my list (*removing 5 instead of the 1 from the first example, and appending 99 to the tail instead of the head in the second example*)? I cannot quite understand why I'm getting these outputs.

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/01/groovy-goodness-pop-and-push-items-in.html

Comment: Which version groovy / java are you using?

Comment: @rao yeah that blogspot post would suggest that pop removes the last item, and push adds the element to the end - but for some reason, my usage of pop and push is doing the opposite. I am currently using groovy-2.5.1.

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-remove-last-item-from.html

Comment: @Rao Ah, found the answer through that blog you shared. Seems that version 2.5 changed the functionality for those two methods. Wonder why the need for the change..

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6396 To be compatible with java.util.Deque

Comment: I found this to be true too. In Groovy Playground, v. 2.6, it gives the last element. In 8.5 groovy (my android project) it returns the first element (??).

```
def args =  [1,2,3,4]
def x = args.pop()
println("gradle 2.6 x: " + x)
```
returns 4

```
def args = [1,2,3,4]
def x = args.pop()
println("Groovy 8.5 x: " + x)
```
Returns 1

Gradle 2.6: reurns 4, Gralde 8.5 returns 1